# Jasper reports: getting errors of class not found

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, jasper-reports

i'm trying to print my report but its not coming in jrviewer. 
this is exception which i'm getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:1034)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:1004)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:499)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillTitle(JRVerticalFiller.java:326)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:262)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:247)
>     at Reports.ReportView.(ReportView.java:36)    at
>   Main.main(Main.java:27)

**This is my code:**
{

```
public class ReportView extends JFrame
{
    public ReportView(String fileName) throws Exception
    {
        this(fileName, null);
    }
    public ReportView(String fileName, HashMap para) throws Exception
    {
        super("ABC Solutions Employee/Project Management System (Report Viewer)");
        DBhandler db = new DBhandler();
        Connection con = db.getconnection();
        try
        {
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileName, para, con);
            JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);
            Container c = getContentPane();
            c.add(viewer);            
        } 
        catch (JRException jRException)
        {

        }
        setBounds(10, 10, 1500, 1500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Try printing the values of fileName, para and con before calling 'fillReport'.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass nulls.  If you don't have any parameters, instantiate your parameter HashMap before passing it to Jasper.  Even if it is empty:

```
   public ReportView(String fileName) throws Exception
   {
        this(fileName, new HashMap< String, String >() );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jasper-report server you cant pass "null" values in graph category column.